# Ruby Float to String error

Tags: ruby

Ruby newbie. What's wrong with this code?

```
city_details['longitude'] + "," + city_details['latitude']
```

I get this error:

```
./player_location.rb:6:in `+': String can't be coerced into Float (TypeError)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like `city_details['longitude']` and `city_details['latitude']` are `Float` values.

You cannot add `Float` to a `String` in Ruby like this. You can either convert everything to `String`, and then `+` them, or use String interpolation.

```
city_details['longitude'].to_s + "," + city_details['latitude'].to_s

"#{city_details['longitude']},#{city_details['latitude']}"
```

Most Rubyists tend to use String interpolation.

Comment: interpolation is faster because ruby creates a unique String object, while using '+' creates a String for each operand. that's why most rubysts use interpolation.

Answer (score 6):

It complains about the fact that you are trying to concatenate a `float` with a `string`.

The better way of doing this is by doing String interpolation:

```
"#{city_details['longitude']}, #{city_details['latitude']}"
```

Other possible solutions:

- You could convert each float to string, by calling the `to_s` method like this:

  `city_details['longitude'].to_s + "," + city_details['latitude'].to_s`
- Or you could use the `join` method:

  `[city_details['longitude'], city_details['latitude']].join(",")`

Comment: the first approach is 2x slower than interpolation, the second maybe worst.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. I edited my answer to point the best approach. However, it is good to know all the possible ways for doing this, because they might be useful in other cases.